# Why I query use group by columns result contain some value , but when I use this value to query the result is empty

Tags: clickhouse

```
Clickhouse Version : ClickHouse server version 21.3.11 revision 54447
Table Settings:
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY datadate
PRIMARY KEY datatime
ORDER BY datatime
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I use this `sql` get a result:

```sql
SELECT
    datadate,
    datatime,
    hostname,
    count(*)
FROM data_1xxxxxx_0_xx_all
WHERE (datadate = '2024-01-02') AND ((datatime >= 1704195210) AND (datatime <= 1704195218)) AND (hostname = 'NSAE_01')
GROUP BY
    datadate,
    datatime,
    hostname
```

```
result : 
┌───datadate─┬───datatime─┬─hostname─┬─count()─┐
│ 2024-01-02 │ 1704195218 │ NSAE_01  │      52 │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

then i use another sql

```
SELECT *
FROM data_1xxxxxx_0_xx_all
WHERE (datadate = '2024-01-02') AND (datatime = 1704195218) AND (hostname = 'NSAE_01')
```

get this result ;

```
Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.044 sec. Processed 335.87 thousand rows, 8.73 MB (7.67 million rows/s., 199.38 MB/s.)
```

i try to find 1st sql's result `datatime=1704195218`

```
SELECT hostname FROM data_1xxxxxx_0_xx_all WHERE (datadate = '2024-01-02') AND (datatime = 1704195218)group by hostname
```

result:

```
┌─hostname────────────────────┐
│ xxxx.xx.com                 │
│ xxxip-15.x.x.5.com          │
│ xxxip_16.x.x.2_60.xx.n5.com │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

What I expect is that the data obtained in the group by results will exist in my clickhouse, rather than when I query using the group by results, there will be no data.

Comment: You're missing a > character in your datatime clause in your 2nd query

Comment: I can't understand. My first query is for data between two timestamps. The result of group by shows that there are 52 data with timestamp 1704195218 and name NSAE_01. But when I query 1704195218 timestamp and name is NSAE_01, they disappeared

Comment: maybe you lost some symbols and it should be `='NSAE_01 '` instead of `='NSAE_01'` ?

Comment: try `hostname LIKE 'NSAE_01%'`

Comment: I thought about this question so I added a sql of
`SELECT hostname FROM data_1625559445198138221_0_60_all WHERE (datadate = '2024-01-02') AND (datatime = 1704195218)group by hostname` , the result set does not contain the hostname of 'NSAE_01'

Answer (score 0):

Let me show it to you more clearly. Here's the WHERE clause of your first query:

```
WHERE (datadate = '2024-01-02') AND ((datatime >= 1704195210) AND (datatime <= 1704195218)) AND (hostname = 'NSAE_01')
```

Here is the WHERE clause of your second query:

```
WHERE (datadate = '2024-01-02') AND (datatime = 1704195218) AND (hostname = 'NSAE_01')
```

What are the odds that you have a bunch of rows where the timestamp is exactly `datatime = 1704195218`? Apparently 0.

Comment: first query datatime between 1704195210 and 1704195218 (total 8s) and  the query result : 
┌───datadate─┬───datatime─┬─hostname─┬─count()─┐
│ 2024-01-02 │ 1704195218 │ NSAE_01  │      52 │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────┘

Comment: The purpose of this operation is to verify whether the result of group by is correct and real. Now it seems that the result of group by cannot be found in the actual query? I'm not sure why. That's why there is this problem